# How to monitor all the connections?

Tags: netstat

I have a server with several users, one of them has a script to connect to an external server.

How can I see the external connection to the server (I know the IP address), so the program used and the user who is running it?

I tried with **netstat -atn** but the it stops outputting after 10 rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lsof` for this; as `root`:

```
lsof -i @address
```

(replacing `address` with the IP address of the server).